# How to Use Resource Route with group prefix without use `as` method

Tags: routes, laravel-5.8

I want to Use Resource Route and Group prefix

Like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'c1'], function () {
    Route::resource('locations', 'LocationController');
  });
```

but its now working.

it's working fine using **as** method like this

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'c1'], function () {
    Route::get('locations', ['as' => 'c1.locations.index', 'uses' => 'LocationController@index']);
    Route::post('locations', ['as' => 'c1.locations.store', 'uses' => 'LocationController@store']);
    Route::get('locations/create', ['as' => 'c1.locations.create', 'uses' => 'LocationController@create']);
    Route::put('locations/{dons}', ['as' => 'c1.locations.update', 'uses' => 'LocationController@update']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'c1'], function () {
    Route::resource('locations', 'LocationController', ['as' => 'c1']);
});
```